# Can we use release pipeline to deploy app on clients on-premises server?

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, release-management

I am just wondering if we can use the Release pipeline service to deploy the build on our clients' on-prem servers or the services are restricted to use within the organization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we use release pipeline to deploy app on client's on-premises server?

Yes.

If you are using the classic UI release pipeline, firstly, you need to [create a deployment group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops#create-a-deployment-group) on your client's on-premises server and use it in your release pipeline.
[image]

Then you can use some tasks to deploy, such as [IIS Web App Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-deployment-on-machine-group?view=azure-devops), [Copy Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

If you are using the yaml pipeline, you need to create a self-hosted agent on client's on-premises server.

You can click [Self-hosted Windows agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) for creating Windows agents, [Self-hosted Linux agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops) for Linux and [Self-hosted macOS agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-osx?view=azure-devops) for macOS.

The following steps are similar to those in the classic UI pipeline.

Comment: Do we need to have any specific services plan as currently, we have the "Basic plan" activated? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RobinT The "Basic plan" is sufficient for these functions~